# How to expose functions in Node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I have a node express app with a simple html, app.js, helper.js

Running command `node app.js` works fine and the page appears and operates correctly at localhost:3000.

I want to be able to call functions that exist IN app.js, called FROM helper.js.  I've seen several examples in StackO about using module.exports but the examples all call the functions the other way around.

Is there a way (ways) to do this? I've seen a little of browserify that seems promising. Is that the only option?

I know the way this is written won't work, but could something like this be done? Such that if I clicked a button in the web page it will console '3.14'?

app.js

```
// Various  lines of node and express code
module.exports = {iLikePi: function() { return '3.14' } }
```

helper.js

```
var app_mod = require('./app.js')
function aButtonClicked() { console.log(app_mod.iLikePi()) }
```

index.html

```
// A button onclick event that calls aButtonClicked()
```

---

And finally, the reason for all this. I am trying to use sqlite3 inside a node app. The only way I can require sqlite3 into a module seems to be in the app.js. It doesn't work when I try to require sqlite3 into helper.js. If there was a way to write a module outside of app.js that can call and use the npm's sqlite3 then that would be an alternative that would be just fine for me!

Thanks everyone,
Frank

Comment: It's still "just JS", so make your helper a real class, not a flat object, and then pass your helper the app in its constructor so it can be bound to `this.app`. Then every function on your helper will have access to the app and any function it owns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely call functions from another file!

Here is an example:

app.js

```
const iLikePie = () => 3.14

module.exports = iLikePie
```

helper.js

```
const app_mod = require('./app.js)

const aButtonClicked = () => console.log(app_mod())
```

This will print 3.14 when aButtonClicked is called.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you for responding. I tried your suggestion and the browser consoled this error: 
    ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: UG. Here is my full comment:

Hi Alex. Thank you for responding. I tried your suggestion and the browser consoled this error: 
    `ReferenceError: require is not defined (helper.js line 1)`

Then, probably because the helper.js was never able to 'require' the app.js, it then error-ed this when aButtonClicked was called:
    `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `vanilla' before initialization`

This `require is not defined` error is what I was getting before and made me think that I couldn't `require` a module that was the actual node application.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your client-side code should never access the SQL server directly. You can expose your data through either an API call / HTTP request or to a certain route.

A client-side POST example:

```
onButtonClick = () => {
  fetch("/math/executepifunc", {
    method: "POST",
    redirect: "follow",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
      num: <value> // something your want server to do with the Pi
     })
}).then(response => {
    // Process your response there
}).catch(err => {throw err;});
}
```

From server:

```
// Mini-middleware grabs all routes under "/math"
var mathFuncRouter = express.Router();
router.post("/executepifunc", (req, res) => {
  const num = req.body.num;
  // execute your function from server
});

// Connect to your custom middleware
app.use("/math", mathFuncRouter);
```